# How can I debug a firefox extension that prevents firefox from closing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When I close Firefox the window dies, but the process hangs forever in memory. The problem definitely comes from my extension (tested with disabling/enabling extensions).

I don't have any specific actions/events tied to closing events. I am using Add-on SDK 1.4a0. The workers, page-mods, context-menus etc. are supposed to simply die nicely. Like they did just a few days ago.

The problem seems to coincide with the coming of Firefox 8.0. It is also reproducible on Firefox 11.0a1. I haven't tested it on earlier version of Firefox, but I don't think is is relevant. It must have come from something I added to the extension.

So here is the question:
How can I debug the process of Firefox closing my extension? Is there some kind of stack of closing things Firefox updates, that I can watch to see where the problem is?

All suggestions are welcome!

EDIT: I fixed my problem by switching branches in the Add-on SDK from master to release.

I'll leave the question open, the general problem is still relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure that workers will simply die if they are still running. Other than that I don't see what could possibly cause this issue.

Comment: Alerts!, sometimes they might cause large problems, but if used right, they can help a lot.

Comment: Do you think that the in background are errors thrown? I developed a small extension that writing console output per observer to a html file - it is just in the beginning: http://rokdd.de/permanent:issuereporter . Maybe you can send me your problematic I can test?

Comment: Since the Browser Toolbox connects to Firefox (is separate process?) it may be able to debug this, see console.logs from addon code etc.